# Oracle integer stored with comma

Tags: oracle, numbers, integer, sqldatatypes

I look at a oracle database and there is a column named `score` it is declared as `INT(12,2)`.

The values that are stored there look like this:
23487.31
0
322.3

So does it mean those are actual float values?
I really crawled through the oracle data type documentation but couldn't find any information regarding the notation of INT(a,b).
(Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT012)

Edit:
`SELECT * FROM v$version;` gives me:

```
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't let you create a table with a column defined as `int(12,2)`. [`int` doesn't take arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF). Are you sure you're seeing `INT` rather then `NUMBER`; and if so, where is that being shown?

Comment: To reiterate what @AlexPoole said - you can't supply a scale or precision when defining a column of type INT. It's simply not allowed, and provokes an `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` error. [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6afc85a0bc876dab5c36db02912590c1) If you have a database where a column is defined as `INT(12,2)` it's not Oracle. Are you referring to the main-line Oracle product, or one of their other products such as MySQL or Rdb? (MySQL won't even allow this. Can't check Rdb as I don't have access to an Rdb server anymore, but I doubt it will work).

Comment: @AlexPoole I got the `INT(12,2)` from `DESCRIBE MYTABLE`. And yes it is a Oracle 10g. I updated my question for more details.

Comment: In Oracle DESCRIBE MYTABLE would should show INTEGER not INT. Unless there was a peculiar aberration in 10.2.0.5.

Comment: But as you can see I operate on an oracle db and `DESCRIBE MYTABLE` gave me the column `score INT(12,2)`

Comment: @Peter - in which client, and which version of DB and client? What do you see for the data type, precision and scale in `all_tab_columns`?

Comment: @AlexPoole As a client I use sqlplus.exe (11.2.0.4.0) from the oracle driver package. I connect to my DB (Oracle 10.2.0.5.0) via Windows ODBC connection (64 Bit). When I set the statement `SELECT DATA_TYPE, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='MYTABLE' AND COLUMN_NAME='score';` it returns: `DATA_TYPE=NUMBER`, `DATA_PRECISION=12`,`DATA_SCALE=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does it mean those are actual float values?

No. Those are numbers with a defined precision of two decimal places.

Oracle supports a FLOAT datatype but it is represented internally as NUMBER. If you want genuine floating-point operations for faster arithmetic it has BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE.

---

> why can't I find anything about the notation of `INT(a,b)`?

Because it's not valid Oracle notation. INT is allowed as a synonym of INTEGER, but it doesn't permit scale or precision parameters. If you try to include them Oracle hurls ORA-00907. (The precision would be nugatory anyway, because an integer can have a precision of zero.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why can't I find anything about the notation of `INT(a,b)`? Do you have an idea about that? Or do you have any source for that?